# Concat two arrays keeping the highest occurance of each item

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to join two arrays keeping all unique entries in the number that they exist in in the array that has more of a particular entry? Confusing I know, here

```
one=[a,a,a,a,a,b]
two=[a,b,c]
```

Would return

```
[a,a,a,a,a,b,c]
```

Thanks in advance. If its somewhere sorry, I can't name  it any simpler and dont know what to look for.

Comment: all __unique__ entries??? in array _one_ `a` is not unique

Comment: what is `a` or `b`... ? a variable with a string, object, function?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT:Post code and effort

Comment: you might want to explain what you're trying to do here because there are so many considerations/ambiguities. like do you mean the most occurrences of a value or the longest sequence? can there be more than one sequence of a particular value in one Array? anything related to order is unclear and several more thoughts/questions.

Comment: All unique entries in the highest number of occurrences, so it would keep 5 as in the example. The order of appearance should be disregarded although they should come in sequences in theory- disregard sequence only count occurrences. I have tried conctating an array that is the difference of two arrays,but that doesn't solve the occurances part of the question.

Comment: Why do you need to look for a pre-made solution? It's not a complex problem, so you should just start to figure out how to write it, then if you get stuck, ask about it.

Comment: I can think of ways of solving it using maps. Wondered if theres a build in method for that as it seems useful to me.

Comment: It's too specific for a built-in method. It's basically a union except that the dupes should be retained. But the task seems pretty simple. You want a new array that has all the members of the first and only the members from the second that are not in the first. So copy the `one` and iterate the `two`, adding each item to the copy after you've verified that it's not already in `one`. Maps work too for an optimized version if the arrays are large.

Comment: Thank everyone for answering and taking their time. Please thumb up Nina Sholz's answer and its a real time saver for everyone woth the same problem:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and count the items and take the max count for returning the values.

```js
var one = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b'],
    two = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    count = new Map,
    result = [];

[one, two].forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        var item = count.get(b);
        if (!item) {
            item = Array.apply(null, { length: aa.length }).fill(0);
            count.set(b, item);
        }
        item[i]++;
    });
});

count.forEach(function (v, k) {
    var l = Math.max.apply(null, v);
    while (l--) {
        result.push(k);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This is one way of solving , working way that is. Thank you Nina!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you should convert both arrays to the two maps where key is the item and the value is number of occurrences of this element.

Then you can compare in which map you have more occurrences of item and using this information you can create a merged table.

```
one=[a,a,a,a,a,b]
two=[a,b,c]

mapOne = {a:5,b:1}
mapTwo = {a:1,b:1,c:1}
```

Comment: You do understand correctly. That was what I was thinking of , wandered of theres a build on method. Thank you